# space skipping does not work with spirit-qi

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I have the following code (floatDecs and intDecs are symbol parser):

```
// Definition of the value parser:
typedef boost::variant<double,int64_t> value_type;
typedef boost::fusion::vector<std::string, value_type> dec_type;
rule<std::string::const_iterator, boost::variant<double,int64_t>(std::string)> value;
value   =   real_parser<double, strict_real_policies<double>>() [ boost::phoenix::bind(boost::lambda::unlambda(floatDecs.add), _r1, _1) ] |
            int_parser<int64_t, 10>()                           [ boost::phoenix::bind(boost::lambda::unlambda(intDecs.add), _r1, _1)   ];

rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string()> ident;
ident %= lexeme[ alpha >> *alnum ];

rule<std::string::const_iterator, dec_type(), boost::spirit::qi::locals<std::string>, space_type> dec;
ident %= ident [_a = _1] >> lit('=') >> value(_a);

boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(testing.cbegin(), testing.cend(), dec, space);
```

The problem: It only works, when I remove space_type in each rule and replace the last line with

```
boost::spirit::qi::parse(testing.cbegin(), testing.cend(), dec);
```

Comment: what's the input you're trying to parse? What does it mean if it "doesn't work"?

Comment: out of curiosity, how did the answer help? I'd like to know. Also, it might help you write a better question in the future. Thank you

Comment: I simply took both sources (his and mine) and compared them to see what I did wrong, since his code is working. He helped me to see, what is wrong with my code, so I marked his answer as helpful.

Comment: FYI "He helped", that'd be _me_ :) "to see what is wrong with my code" - and I was curious what that might have been. I might be able to better help in the future, knowing what pitfalls tripped others up in the past.

Comment: He helped me to find this line in my code: ident %= ident [_a = _1] >> lit('=') >> value(_a);<br>It is obviously wrong.

Comment: Ah, it needed to be `dec` instead of `ident`. Yeah, I assumed that was a copy error in the question only :) Glad to be of help. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear to me what the problem is you are asking about. Regardless, here is a version fixing some issues with the code you posted, and showing that parsing works ok with the skipper:

See it live on **[http://liveworkspace.org/code/6GVK4$0](http://liveworkspace.org/code/6GVK4%240)**

Output

```
phrase_parse: true
allo1 = 213.13f
```

Code

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;

int main()
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    typedef boost::variant<double,int64_t> value_type;
    typedef std::pair<std::string, value_type> dec_type;

    qi::rule<It, value_type(std::string)> value = 
        qi::real_parser<double, qi::strict_real_policies<double>>() /*[ phx::bind(boost::lambda::unlambda(floatDecs.add), qi::_r1, qi::_1) ]*/ |
        qi::int_parser<int64_t, 10>()                               /*[ phx::bind(boost::lambda::unlambda(intDecs.add), qi::_r1, qi::_1)   ]*/;

    qi::rule<It, std::string()> ident = qi::lexeme[ qi::alpha >> *qi::alnum ];

    qi::rule<It, dec_type(), qi::space_type, qi::locals<std::string> > declaration;
    declaration %= ident [qi::_a = qi::_1] >> '=' >> value(qi::_a);

    std::string testing("allo1 = 213.13");
    dec_type parsed;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(testing.cbegin(), testing.cend(), declaration, qi::space, parsed);
    std::cout << "phrase_parse: " << std::boolalpha << ok << "\n";

    using namespace karma;
    std::cout << format(auto_ << " = " << (double_ << 'f' | int_) << eol, parsed);
}
```